# How to animate a layout in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

In my Activity screen,half of the screen contain a layout.When Activity loaded it visible and after 10 seconds it will be get down slowly finally it will be not visible to user.But it get down slowly.How i can do it.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: r u showing and hiding view visibility?and do you want to show vertical scale animation?where is your code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your `res\anim` folder (create the folder if it's not there) create `slide_out_down.xml` and paste the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

to start the animation and hide the view use this

```
 private void hideView(final View view){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_down);
    //use this to make it longer:  animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Comment: Your code is help full but i have layout for which im applying this translation  is on middle of other layout's.The translation is going over the bottom layout.i want to be happen the translation from the back of bottom layout.

Comment: Can you explain what you need a bit more?

Comment: In my parent layout divided into 3 parts.1 and 3 parts are fixed for header and footer and 2 parts for anther layout.When my activity is loaded the 2 part will be get down slowly in between 1 and 3 layouts.But your code ,the layout get down over the 3 rd layout.

Comment: Can you give me you mail id so that i can explain my situation in form of screen shots.

Comment: Ok, then just add a FrameLayout between header and footer, and inside that put your 2nd layout. This way when you animate your 2nd view it will stay between your  header and footer.

Comment: i have tried using framelayout too the layout is moving down over the layout which is below to it.

Comment: You put your 2nd view inside the FrameLayout and animated your 2nd view?

Comment: You also have a few other questions not marked as answered. People wont help you in the future if you continue like this. I would suggest going back to your previous questions and mark them as answered. You can do that by clicking the check left of the answer you want to accept.

Comment: same like get down,i need move up just for same layout.can you tell how i can do?

Comment: create another anim file named slide_in_up.xml. And paste in this http://pastebin.com/708sW29P Let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void animateLayout(){
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layoutId);
        layout.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(50000);
    }
```

The above code will make the view go invisible very slowly.

`setDuration(50000)` //change the number according to your need. It varies the speed of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FragmentActivity and Fragment for this and add animation to the fragment

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
 <scale
  android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
  android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="1000" 
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

// gone layout
     collapse(recipientLayout);
//show layout
      expand(recipientLayout);

    public void expand(final LinearLayout v) {
    v.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    /*if (v.isShown()) {
        collapse(v);
    } else */{
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                                               Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int) (targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        a.setDuration((int) (targtetHeight + 600));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

}

public void collapse(final LinearLayout v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                                           Transformation t) {
            /*if (v.isShown()) {
                collapse(v);
            }*/
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight
                        - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration((int) (v.getLayoutParams().height + 600));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```