# Layout Animations in Android

Tags: android, layout

i made a  calendar application on android using API 11 what i need is i want to add animations in it while my application runs.Can anybody help me at this with the help of source code for both layout.main and for Main.can anybody paste the code for it?

Comment: this is what you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) about Animation.

and also check this duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340851/how-to-animate-a-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample from here http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html
There are common animation for layouts.
Also you can check your android SDK folder /samples/android-11/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis - here the classes which demonstrates animations